# can we control seekbar in window manager?

Tags: android, seekbar, window-managers

I want to control my seekbar from window manager. I mean, I want to called my layout from window manager, and i want to control my seekbar from that window manager. From my code, I can't move my seekbar eventhough the layout is appear. Below is my code:

```
View view;
WindowManager wm;
AudioManager audioManager;

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
  LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
  WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
          WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
          WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
          WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
          WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
          PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);
  wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
  view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.volume, null);
  params.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
  wm.addView(view, params);

  audioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
     SeekBar volControl = (SeekBar)view.findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
     volControl.setProgress(0);
     volControl.setMax(100);
     volControl.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

 @Override
 public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 }

 @Override
 public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 }

 @Override
 public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int arg1, boolean arg2) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     Typeface tf2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Raleway-Regular.ttf");
     TextView text1 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.volume_value);
     text1.setTypeface(tf2);
     arg1 = arg1 / 1;
     arg1 = arg1 * 1;
     text1.setText(String.valueOf(arg1));
  //audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, arg1, 0);
 }
});

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    wm.removeView(view);
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
```